# How can i point with a RewriteRule in a file inside subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

Im would RewriteUrl url for calling file inside a folder/subfolder
as if were in a root

real path:
domain.com/folder/subfolder/file.php

what i would:
domain.com/customer/customer_name
(customer is not a real folder)

At the end
/customer/customer_name
is created dinamically from DB

customer <-- used as a param in a page
customer_name <-- is used as a param in a page

Comment: Please add examples for requested URL and what you want to rewrite them to internally. In its current form the question is impossible to be answered. You say things don't work, but do not tell what that means and why you actually want to achieve.

Comment: Hi  arkascha
i ve edit my question, i hope is more clear now

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is still very hard to understand what you are actually trying to achieve. Certainly rewrite rules can target any file reachable by the http server, be it in a subfolder or not. And certainly you can interpret folder parts pf the path component of a URL as dynamic parts. You can see endless examples for that in thousands of answers here on SO. So where is your question different?